# German Residence Permit Malta Visa

Tags: visas, europe

I am an Indian master student in Germany and I have a German Residence Permit, and I plan to visit Malta in June.
Do I need a tourist visa for Malta?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you travel with a tourism purpose, you don't. Both countries are part of the Schengen agreement and your German residence permit is a Schengen visa.

Comment: To be precise, the German residence permit isn't actually a Schengen *visa,* but it does allow the bearer to stay in other Schengen countries for up to 90 days in any 180-day period.